# Sqoop "import-all-tables" unable to import all tables

Tags: java, sql-server, hive, sqoop

this is the sqoop command which I am using to import data from SQL Server to Hive 
`sqoop-import-all-tables  --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://ip.ip.ip.ip\MIGERATIONSERVER;port=1433;username=sa;password=blablaq;database=sqlserverdb" --create-hive-table --hive-import --hive-database hivemtdb` 
The problem is that `sqlserverdb` has about 100 tables but when i issue this command it is just importing 6 or 7 random tables to hive. This behavior is really strange for me. I am unable to find where I am doing mistake. 
**EDIT :1**

```
Warning: /usr/hdp/2.4.3.0-227/accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
16/10/13 13:17:38 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.4.3.0-227
16/10/13 13:17:38 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override
16/10/13 13:17:38 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.
16/10/13 13:17:38 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
16/10/13 13:17:38 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
16/10/13 13:17:38 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM [UserMessage] AS t WHERE 1=0
16/10/13 13:17:38 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/hdp/2.4.3.0-227/hadoop-mapreduce
Note: /tmp/sqoop-sherry/compile/c809ee201c0aec1edf2ed5a1ef4aed4c/UserMessage.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
16/10/13 13:17:39 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-sherry/compile/c809ee201c0aec1edf2ed5a1ef4aed4c/UserMessage.jar
16/10/13 13:17:39 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of UserMessage
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.4.3.0-227/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.4.3.0-227/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
16/10/13 13:17:40 INFO impl.TimelineClientImpl: Timeline service address: http://machine-02-xx:8188/ws/v1/timeline/
16/10/13 13:17:40 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at machine-02-xx/xxx.xx.xx.xx:8050
16/10/13 13:17:42 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation
16/10/13 13:17:42 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
16/10/13 13:17:42 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1475746531098_0317
16/10/13 13:17:43 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1475746531098_0317
16/10/13 13:17:43 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://machine-02-xx:8088/proxy/application_1475746531098_0317/
16/10/13 13:17:43 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1475746531098_0317
16/10/13 13:17:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1475746531098_0317 running in uber mode : false
16/10/13 13:17:48 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/10/13 13:17:52 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/10/13 13:17:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1475746531098_0317 completed successfully
16/10/13 13:17:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 30
        File System Counters
                FILE: Number of bytes read=0
                FILE: Number of bytes written=156179
                FILE: Number of read operations=0
                FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                FILE: Number of write operations=0
                HDFS: Number of bytes read=87
                HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
                HDFS: Number of read operations=4
                HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
                HDFS: Number of write operations=2
        Job Counters
                Launched map tasks=1
                Other local map tasks=1
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=3486
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
                Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=1743
                Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=1743
                Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=2677248
        Map-Reduce Framework
                Map input records=0
                Map output records=0
                Input split bytes=87
                Spilled Records=0
                Failed Shuffles=0
                Merged Map outputs=0
                GC time elapsed (ms)=30
                CPU time spent (ms)=980
                Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=233308160
                Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=3031945216
                Total committed heap usage (bytes)=180879360
        File Input Format Counters
                Bytes Read=0
        File Output Format Counters
                Bytes Written=0
16/10/13 13:17:52 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 12.6069 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
16/10/13 13:17:52 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 0 records.
16/10/13 13:17:52 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM [UserMessage] AS t WHERE 1=0
16/10/13 13:17:52 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column SendDate had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive
16/10/13 13:17:52 INFO hive.HiveImport: Loading uploaded data into Hive

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.4.3.0-227/hive/lib/hive-common-1.2.1000.2.4.3.0-227.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
OK
Time taken: 1.286 seconds
Loading data to table sqlcmc.usermessage
Table sqlcmc.usermessage stats: [numFiles=1, totalSize=0]
OK
Time taken: 0.881 seconds
Note: /tmp/sqoop-sherry/compile/c809ee201c0aec1edf2ed5a1ef4aed4c/DadChMasConDig.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.4.3.0-227/hive/lib/hive-common-1.2.1000.2.4.3.0-227.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
OK
```

Comment: Put `--verbose` (_to check extended logs_) in your command and check if there are any error/exception

Comment: yes I tried it with --verbose too but it isn't showing any exception or error.

Comment: Try `sqoop list-tables --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://ip.ip.ip.ip\MIGERATIONSERVER;port=1433;username=sa;password=blablaq;database=sqlserverdb"`. Is it showing all 100 tables?

Comment: yea it shows all tables. but I saw something that it is showing a list of all tables and I realize that it imports just first 6 tables all the time (from the list which I have seen now)

Comment: is it some problem with mapreduce as it sqoop uses MR at backend and I have to pass specific argument to turn it on to import all tables.

Comment: are you using 1 mapper (`-m 1`) or `--autoreset-to-one-mapper` ?

Comment: There is no limit to import only 6 tables.

Comment: I am not using anything like `(-m 1)` or `--autoreset-to-one-mapper`. Should I use this? what is the purpose of using this and what would be the complete command then?

Comment: Try checking the java class generated by your Sqoop query.

Comment: only these 6 tables have primary keys?

Comment: Does all of your tables have primary keys? If did not specify any of the above mentioned properties sqoop will use 4 mappers

Comment: I guess some of them have primary key and some of them doesn't have. what should I do in this case?

Comment: Put `--autoreset-to-one-mapper` in the end of your import command. Let me know if it works

Comment: ok it is very strange. When I added `--autoreset-to-one-mapper` to my command, now its imported 9 tables. without adding this, it was importing 6 tables but still many tables are missing and didn't get import.

Comment: You can try with only 1 mapper in this way it does not split task in parallel and import whole table with 1 connection. Remove  `--autoreset-to-one-mapper` add `-m 1` in your command.

Comment: Do one thing. Share last few lines of the logs shown on terminal after adding `verbose`

Comment: Dear @devツ thanks alot for getting involve in this for such a long. now I am using this command `sqoop-import-all-tables  --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://xx.xx.51.xx\MIGERATIONSERVER;port=1433;username=sa;password=xxxx;database=sqldb" --create-hive-table --hive-import --hive-database hivedb -m 1` but it still imports just few tables (20 tables out of all tables). I am adding logs in question in EDITED part. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

First of all `import-all-tables` will run import table for all the tables.

If you does not define, number of mapper in the job, Sqoop will pick by default 4 mappers. So, it needs table to have primary key or you specify `--split-by` column name.

If this is the case, you will see error like:

> ERROR tool.ImportAllTablesTool: Error during import: No primary key could be found for table test. Please specify one with --split-by or perform a sequential import with '-m 1'.

So you can use 1 mapper which will make your import process slow.

Better way is to add `--autoreset-to-one-mapper`, it will import tables with primary key with the number of mappers mentioned in the command and it will automatically use 1 mapper for the tables without primary key.

---

Coming to your problem,

**sqoop import failed for table `DadChMasConDig`**.

I don't know why it is not logged on console.

In importing this table there could be exception like

> Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Hive does not support the SQL type for column `<somecolumn>`

For example, `varbinary` is not supported.

If you import data only in HDFS, it should not be a problem. You can try:

`sqoop-import-all-tables  --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://ip.ip.ip.ip\MIGERATIONSERVER;port=1433;username=sa;password=blablaq;database=sqlserverdb"`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the following worked for me. Though typically --create-hive-table and --hive-overwrite don't go together and doesn't make sense together. But no other combination worked and each time only 3 of 10 or a fraction of tables were getting imported

```
 sqoop import-all-tables \
       --connect jdbc:mysql://<mysql-url>/my_database \
       --username sql_user \
       --password sql_pwd \
       --hive-import \
       --hive-database test_hive \
       --hive-overwrite \
       --create-hive-table \
       --warehouse-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/test_hive.db \
       -m 1
```