# User does not belong to supergroup

Tags: sqoop

I am getting error while running Sqoop import-all-table command.
`chgrp: changing ownership of 'hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/retail_db.db/categories/part-m-00000': User does not belong to supergroup`.

The command is `sqoop import-all-tables --connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retail_db" --username retail_dba -P  --hive-import   --hive-database retail_db --create-hive-table --hive-overwrite -m 2`

I have checked following file but dfs.permission is set to false.

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ locate hdfs-site.xml
/etc/hadoop/conf.empty/hdfs-site.xml
/etc/hadoop/conf.impala/hdfs-site.xml
/etc/hadoop/conf.pseudo/hdfs-site.xml
/etc/impala/conf.dist/hdfs-site.xml
```

SuperGroup is not present in /etc/group

Please suggest to resolve this.

Comment: its ERROR or INFO? can you see database retail_db in hive prompt?

Comment: Thanks @Nirmal Ram for quick response, I have checked only categories table is updated in hive and no other table is created under hive.

Comment: have you checked by moving to retail_db database -> "use retail_db;" ? is your metastore using Derby database?

Comment: can you post the full log you get when running sqoop job

Comment: I am using Quickstart Vm from cloudera and it is using mysql as db .As far as logs i am not sure  of correct path for logs . I tried  sqoop logs under /var/log/sqoop2/logs but it does not show nothing much.

Comment: Sqoop command sends with `Note: /tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/00e5461406023b65452de5bbe90576a1/customers.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.`

Comment: @Anaadih.pradeep check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40046187/3929393)

Answer (score 0):

after reboot of machine somehow i was able to run the below query was same Info message but with all data in all tables. 
`sqoop import-all-tables --connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retail_db" --username retail_dba -P  --hive-import   --hive-database retail_db --create-hive-table --hive-overwrite`